# Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html, while display currency symbols

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unicode

I am trying to display currency symbols using their unicodes in angularjs. I created an array of unicodes, and used ng-repeat for displaying each currency symbol. I also used Strict Contextual Escaping, But i am getting  Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html

This is my index.html.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="currency in currencies">
      <span data-ng-bind-html="currency | toHtml"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my app.js

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
  .filter('toHtml', function($sce) {
      return function(input) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    }
 })
 .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.currencies = $sce.trustAsHtml(['U+20B9', 'U+20AC', 'U+0024']);
 });
```

Comment: I found an alternate way to solve my issue. I used javaScript/Json code instead of unicode. for eg: \u20B9. Now I don't need to call Strict Contextual Escaping.

Answer (score 1):

> Attempted to trust a **non-string value** in a content requiring a
>   string: Context: html

You are trying to call `$sce.trustAsHtml` on an array. It can only be called on a a string.

You need to call it on each unicode value instead of trying to call it on the entire array:

```
var currencies = [];
var unicodes = ['U+20B9', 'U+20AC', 'U+0024'];

angular.forEach(unicodes, function(uc) {
  currencies.push($sce.trustAsHtml(uc));
});

$scope.currencies = currencies;
```